# text align vertical is not working in div?

Tags: css

```
.st_content_heading{
width:500px;
height:250px;
background:red;
border:1px solid #ccc;
float:left;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}
<div class="st_content_heading" style="vertical-align:middle;">Content for  class "st_content_out" Goes Here</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you float the element you lose the table-cell status.

```
.st_content_heading{
width:500px;
height:250px;
background:red;
border:1px solid #ccc;
/* float:left; take this out */ 
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working.. if i need to use "float:left" at that time what can i do?

Comment: Put wrap an extra div around it and float that.

Comment: If the answer is correct the best practice is to click on the checkmark that is next to my answer. This allows other users to figure out which answer is right.

Answer (score 0):

This Solution Matched me perfectly. Even if it is a link or just a text inside the div, this CSS Class could vertically align the content inside the DIV

```
.verticalCenterDivText{
    height: 29px;
    line-height: 29px;
}
```

Hope this helps.